# Singleton object scope between spring IOC container and Application server Level

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, ejb

We have an EJB application where the singleton classes are initialized on server start up (these classes are packed in application lib as common jar). Instance for this singleton classes created successfully. But When these singleton classes where getting access through spring container (MVC), new instanceof the same singleton class getting created. ie The instance which are created at the time of server start up unknown to spring container.

Can anyone help how to create a single class instance which can be access across the container?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html

Comment: Please show your code and spring config.

Comment: We want to know how to achieve this?